# Почему ascii символы кириллицы отрицательные в языке Си?

Tags: c, кириллица, символы

Почему в консоли Windows программа на языке Си выдает отрицательный ascii-код символа из кириллицы? 
Я понимаю, что код ascii кириллицы выходит за пределы 127, и поэтому использую unsigned char. Но как-то не помогает.

Небольшие куски программы:

```
int main()
{
    char *word_replace_from = NULL;

    SetConsoleCP(1251);         // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);   // установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток вывода

    word_replace_from = inputWordReplaceFrom();
}

char getchr()
{
    unsigned char c;
    c = _getch();

    if (c == KEY_SAVE_EXIT)
        c = NULL;

    if (c == '\r')
        c = '\n';

    if (c != '\b' && c != NULL)
        printf_s("%c", c);

    return c;
}
char *inputWordReplaceFrom()
{

    char *str = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));       // указатель на первый элемент новой строки
    int length = 0;                                 // счётчик количества символов

    printf("Максимальное количество символов: %d. Вводить можно только буквы русского и английского алфавита. Введите слово ", MAXLENGTHLINE);

    while ((length < MAXLENGTHLINE) && ((*(str + length) = getchr()) != '\n') && (*(str + length) != NULL))
    {
        printf("\n str = %d \n", (*(str + length)));
        if (
            (64 < *(str + length) && *(str + length) < 91)
            || (96 < *(str + length) && *(str + length) < 123) ||
            (191 < *(str + length) && *(str + length) < 256) ||
            (*(str + length) == 168) || (*(str + length) == 184)
            )
        {
            length++;
            if (length == MAXLENGTHLINE)
            {
                printf("\n \t ------ Информация \n ");
                printf("\t ------Превышена максимальная длина строки. Ввод завершен. ");
            }
        } 
        else
        {
            printf("\nОшибка. Можно вводить только буквы русского и английского алфавита.\n");
            if (length)
            {
                length--;
                printf("\b \b");
            }
        }
        str = (char*) realloc(str, (length + 2) * sizeof(char));
    }
    // Метка: конец строки символов
    *(str + length) = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

Comment: `char *str` и где тут `unsigned`?

Comment: У вас значение  `unsigned char` отрицательное получается?

Comment: Где у вас вывод кода символа?

Comment: @banme unsigned char *str писать нельзя, ругается компилятор.

Comment: @nick-volynkin при использовании в условии if, и до него printf("\n str = %d \n", (*(str + length)));

Comment: @tutankhamun printf("\n str = %d \n", (*(str + length)));

Comment: Точно. Просмотрел. Замените "%d" на "%hhu". "%d" всегда выводит число со знаком

Comment: @tutankhamun у меня дальше это значение используется в if, чтобы определить, находится ли  символ среду нужных кодов ascii русского и английского алфавита.

Comment: "unsigned char *str писать нельзя, ругается компилятор" Вот по этому поводу нужны подробности. Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @tutankhamun «Значение тип *char нельзя использовать для инициализации сущности типа «unsigned char».»

Comment: `unsigned char *str = (unsigned char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` Вы так написали?

Comment: @tutankhamun Да, всё верно.

Comment: И компилятор ругается именно на эту строку?

Answer (score 2):

Вы работаете на платформе, на которой тип `char` является *знаковым*. Это означает, что при ширине типа `char` в 8 бит, он будет традиционно иметь диапазон `-128..127`. Поэтому очевидно, что ваши сравнения значений типа `char` с числами типа `191`, `168` и т.п. смысла не имеют и иметь не могут.

По этой причине "не срабатывают" ваши условия в `if`. По этой же самой причине ваш `printf` печатает отрицательные значения.

Если вы хотите на уровне вашего кода работать с кодами символов в диапазоне `0..255`, то либо явно вручную приводите все значения типа `char` к типу `unsigned char`, либо ройтесь в настройках компилятора, чтобы сделать тип `char` беззнаковым сам по себе.

---

Недоумение также вызывает выражение `(*(str + length) != NULL)`. Что тут имелось в виду? `NULL` - константа, предназначенная для использования в *указательных* контекстах, т.е. ее, например, можно сравнивать с указателями. У вас же она вдруг сравнивается с `char`.

Посмотрев внимательнее, мой зоркий глаз заметил, что значение типа `char`, якобы равное `NULL`, действительно может возвращаться из рукописной функции `getchr` (мне сначала показалось, что это стандартный `getchar`). Но это не делает ситуацию лучше. `NULL` нельзя присваивать значениям типа `char` или сравнивать со значениями типа `char`.

Comment: Подозреваю что имеется в виду конец строки.

Comment: @Cerbo: А, я сначала, не заметил, что это возвращается из рукописной функции `getchr`. Но это все равно возмутительно.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в формате в вызове функции `printf`. "%d" - выводит целое со знаком. Без знака выводит модификатор "%u", но по-умолчанию он выводит тип `int`, а это, как правило, 4-байта. Чтобы выводить только один байт  перед "u" нужно поставить модификатор "hh". В итоге строка должна выглядеть так:

```
printf("\n str = %hhu \n", (*(str + length)));
```

Comment: Дальше идёт if, в котором я проверяю, принадлежит ли код символа к нужному диапазону (в русском или английском алфавите символ).

Comment: @Sadykh И в чем проблема? Условие тоже не срабатывает?

Comment: не срабатывает :(